# Error: Could not find or load main class; SalesForce bulk API

Tags: java, maven, salesforce

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Here ");
    }
}
```

Here is the [pom.xml](https://github.com/forcedotcom/wsc/blob/master/pom.xmlemphasized) I'm using. It gives me error for any code i run after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will probably due to, you are trying to run this main method in a package which contains many other dependencies from the pom and other classes. So, when the main method is called, it will try to load not only things inside the main method, but also the other things in that class as well. At that time, the corresponding dependencies will fail to load since the class is started independently.

**NB**: I have also faced the same issue. Couldn't able to find the solution from anywhere. At last, I moved the main method containing class into a totally different package which is independent from other common dependencies of the project.

You better try to move the main method into an independent package.

Comment: I don't have anything else in that project. Removed everything else and tried Main method in another package also.